# Android: Tips on CameraPreview

Tags: android, layout, camera, preview

I managed to create the class that allows me to have a preview of the room (which is supported by a SurfaceView), and thus far everything is ok, the code work.
Now I was wondering if it was possible to create buttons (or more generally any other object) on this Surface.

I tried to load the layout with setContentView (my_layout) but doing so is not loaded (or at least, not shown) the SurfaceView object. So as I seemed to understand, you can only load one of the two, or maybe I missing something?

Sorry for that bad English, but this text was generated by Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a framelayout and add buttons. 
Or construct your view with addContentView

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null), new     ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Man, thanks for the help, I'll try right away, but before going any further, I would like any other advice would otherwise be useless to proceed.

I asked this because my idea is to create objects of this preview of the camera and then put them in motion (using threads).

Now I also want to figure out if I'm wrong way of thinking about the program (so I can lean on the libraries that do all this automatically), or my idea would work and I have to just go ahead with the development of this application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with transparent background and put it above your surface view.

Good thing is to create a `FrameLayout` with 2 elements in it. 1st being your SurfaceView with match_parent for both width and height so it occupies the whole parent `FrameLayout`.

2nd would be your layout with transparent background which can occupy, for example, part of the parent FrameLayout.

So then your SurfaceView gets created first and above it there will be your transparent layout with buttons.

That could work for kind of control panel or something but if you want kind of augmented reality you can have a look at the OpenCV SDK for Android where they do change the camera preview picture applying filters to it etc.

Comment: I was looking for just that, some library that would allow me to handle the augmented reality, thanks for the tip.

Anyway back to the earlier I had already tried to crare a layout with transparent backgrounds and add us under the SurfaceView object, but no, it did not work (if you want I can add the code).

Sorry for that bad English, but this text was generated by Google Translate.